# Snakemake reports

Tags: report, snakemake

I would like to create a report for Snakemake which includes both runtime reports and results from a workflow.

```
snakemake --report report.html
```

Allow me to create wonderful runtime reports

This page describes one way to do reports:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html#

However, the tutorial described another way:

```
[https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v3.11.0/snakefiles/utils.html][2]
```

Is the way described in the tutorial depracted?
What is the best way to create reports including run time, software versions AND results?
Is there any way to create reports in RTF or other formats which can be edited using text-software

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use reports from recent snakemake version?

Comment: Well this is actually my question. So the way described in the tutorial is depracted and the new way is described here? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html# If so, how can I extend my report including also my name software versions and some text?

Comment: Perhaps use python's `print` to add info of your interest to report file?